# Use scroll position to animate frames

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to use the vertical scroll bar position, to load consecutive images into a div every 20pixels while scrolling down and then reversing the loads while scrolling up to creat an animation effect back and forth. Im new to programming and really struggling with this one. Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry but this site is for specific problems. You can try something by yourself and ask to us when you suffer a specific issue. You can start googling about `javascript on scroll load elements` and you'll obtain millions of results. Good luck :)

Comment: I googled it before I posted this question and got caught in their search bubble so kept getting the same results when trying to search in different ways. I've worked it now anyway.